# What is the difference between int () and int (*)()?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a class template that identifies functions, in which I can identify when a function is specializing the class model for `R (*) ()`, but in `std::function` you can declare  `return_type ()`, and `std::is_same< int(), int (*) () >.::value` is zero.

What does this `int ()` statement mean and what is the difference between `int ()` and  
`int (*) ()`?

Updated: So  `int ()` is function declaration or function type and `int (*)()` is pointer to function.But waht is the type function of `int (std::string::)()`?It's something like `int std::string::()`, or like in `std::function`  `int(const std::string&)`?How i can make this program output 1?

`#include <iostream>
template<typename A,typename B>
struct IsSame{
  enum{
      value = 0};
};
template<typename A>
struct IsSame<A,A>{
    enum{
        value = 1  
    };
};
typedef int (SumType)(int,int)const;
class X{
  public:
        SumType sum;    
};
int X::sum(int a,int b)const{
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << IsSame< int (const std::string&,int,int)const,
                       decltype( &X::sum)>::value;
}`

Comment: One is a function and another is pointer to a function.

Comment: But what is the use of int ()? So int () is declaration of  a function signature and int (*) () is pointer to function.

Comment: There is also the equivalent for non static member function :[What type is int(int)& or int(int) const &?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766581/what-type-is-intint-or-intint-const)

Comment: @Diego Teixeira de Souza int (std::string::*) () is a pointer to a non-static member function in the class std::string that takes no arguments and returns an int. I know, it's crazy

Comment: Zebrafish is right. C++ inherits and extends its declarator syntax from C, all the way back to "K&R". The idea was to use a syntax close to the one at the point of use. So `int *f()` is a function returning a pointer to `int` because `*f()` is what one use to call such a function and deref the result. Likewise, `int (*f)()` is a pointer to a function returning an `int` because you would first deref the pointer and then call the function (nevermind that this first step is syntactically optional). Read declarators inside out and consider precedence, e.g. `int *a[4]` is an array, not a pointer.

Answer (score 8):

A function has a type like `void()` and if you take the address of that you get a pointer to that function `void(*)()`. They are not the same type, although a function can decay to a pointer to a function in a similar way that arrays decay to pointers to the first member.

This means you can declare a function:

```
void f();
```

and assign it to a pointer to a function (of the same signature):

```
void (*p_to_f)() = f;
```

and the function decays to a pointer to a function.
This is why I think it can be difficult to understand the difference between `void()` and `void(*)()`, but they are distinct types, and that difference can be important in templates (where this decay doesn't necessarily occur).

One important example of when decay doesn't happen is when matching template specialisations. Consider what `std::function` does for example:

```
template <class>
class function;

template <class R, class ... Args>
class function<R(Args...)> { /* ... stuff ... */ };
```

The fact that the specialisation is on a function type is different than if it were specialised on a pointer-to-function type.

```
function<void(int,int)> f;//matches specialisation
function<void(*)(int,int)> g;//does not match specialisation
```

**In response to the OP's comment (now deleted):**
In order to also match pointers to functions you can do:

```
template <class R, class ... Args>
function<R(*)(Args...)> : function<R(Args...>{};
```

which essentially means you treat functions and pointers to functions the same. If you want to match as many functions as you can, you also have to consider member functions, const member functions and `noexcept` functions (as of C++17). If you want to be completely thorough, there's also `&`, `&&`, `const &`, `const&&`, `volatile`, etc... but I wouldn't worry about those unless they actually come up.

Comment: @DiegoTeixeiradeSouza in template specialisations, yes you will have to specialise them separately.

Comment: But it makes more sense to specialize only for int ().

Comment: Depends on how you're going to use this, if this comes from a `decltype(f)` where `f` can be anything at all then you have to care about the differences.